# Likes missing in vimeo api response

Tags: vimeo-api

Sometimes I see that the likes and view for a video obtained using  vimeo API response goes missing due to some reason . Why does this happen ? Is there a work around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a users settings they can chose "I prefer not to share statistics on my video clip pages". Video responses in the API respect this setting, and will not include plays.

Likes should always appear, so if you do not see them please contact Vimeo directly with as much information as possible.

Comment: I am using vimeo simple API so will there be more than one page in the API response considering the fact that only 20 fields in one page ?

Comment: The simple API is limited to 20 items per page, and up to three pages of content. If you would like more, you must use the Advanced API.